# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   $(lblName).innerText = $(ddlNameList).options[$(ddlNameList).selectedIndex].text;
```

Does any know why the above line of code works in chrome but fails in Internet Explorer 11 with the following error

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference

Comment: `options` is not a property of the `jQuery` object (which is what `$(ddlNameList)` is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(lblName).innerText = $('#' + ddlNameList + ' option:selected').val();
```